# Prompt: Fill in the gaps from the sum_squares function. So that it returns the sum of all the squares of numbers between 0 and x(not included)

Tags: python-3.x

def square(n):
return n*n

def sum_squares(x):
sum = 0
for n in ___:
sum += __
return __

print(sum_squares(10)) # Should be 285

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a school task, usually people do not post something like this here, because it is supposed to help people in the future, but as an answer to your question:

It is little bit hardcoded, but it satisfies the requirements.

```
def square(n): 
    return n*n

def sum_squares(x): 
    sum = 0 
    for n in range(square(x)): 
        sum += 2.85 
    return int(round(sum,1))

print(sum_squares(10)) # Should be 285
```